# Trying to count how many numbers are in each line of a text file

Tags: python

Q.txt:

```
4; -9; -1; 9; -1; -3; 8; 8; 0; -9; -8 
7; 6; 5; -6; 5; -4; 2; 1; -1; -6; 0; 3; -7; 9; 9; 6; -5; -8; 1; -8; -1; -1
-8; -6; -6; -5; -6; -8; -4; -2; 8; -3; 3; 6; 4; -9; 10; 2; -4; 7; -5; 0; -3; 7; -7; 6; -10; 8; -9; 9; 2; -1; -6; 6; -5; 8; 0; 3; 6; -10; -2; 8; -6; -5; 9; 10
```

trying to determine a way to read the text file line by line and tell the user how many numbers are on each line.

```
lines=0
with open('Q.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line=f.readline()
        lines=lines+1
        x = line.split("; ")
        print(x)
        print("The count for this line is", len(x))#thought this would give me the count for that line
        print(lines) # to see for which line has said length
```

Comment: A clever trick to do this would be simply reading each line, and then figuring out the number of semicolons on each line. The number of numbers on each line is the number of semicolons + 1.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.
Unless you have trouble with reading the file, you should hard-code your input lines.  What output do you already have, and what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('Q.txt') as fd:
    for line in fd.readlines():
        print(f"The count for this line is: {len(line.split('; '))}")
```